# aJax file upload, Chrome + IE, mobiles?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have updated my question. I have got the following code which works on Chrome and IE, not tested on any other browsers yet. It doesn't work on mobile phones running Chrome though, and it doesn't work on Opera on an iPad.

Is this due to the code im using being unsupported, which im guessing in the case, if so, is there an alternative?

```
function submitFile() {
    var theFile = document.getElementById("image").files[0];
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onload = function(e) {
        document.getElementById("imageUpload").innerHTML = "UPLOAD COMPLETE!";
    };

    xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
        if (e.lengthComputable) {
            var currentPercentage = Math.round(e.loaded / e.total * 100);
            document.getElementById("imageUpload").innerHTML = "UPLOAD IMAGE " + currentPercentage + "%";
            document.getElementById("imageUpload").style.backgroundSize = currentPercentage + "% 100%";
        }
    };

    xhr.open("POST", "php/submitMessage.php", true);
    xhr.send(theFile);
}
```

Additional question, what would be a good way to retrieve the stored location of the file so I can submit that with the rest of the form, which will be submitted separately to the image? Im guessing the only way would be to retrieve it as a string using the responseHTML?

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: Try checking this line `var theFile = document.getElementById("image").files[0];` Sometimes the Input File Object can generate problems.

Comment: @LucasPiske it does seem to upload the file though on mobile browsers still, just not show the progress.